# Deleting rows in a sequence for MULTIPLE lists in R

Tags: r, list, data.table

I know how to delete rows in in a sequence for a SINGLE list:

```
data <- data.table('A' = c(1,2,3,4), 'B' = c(900,6,'NA',2))
row.remove <- data[!(data$A = seq(from=1,to=4,by=2) )]
```

However, I would like to know how to do so with MULTIPLE lists.

Code I've tried:

```
file.number <- c(1:5)
data <- setNames(lapply(paste(file.number,".csv"), read.csv, paste(file.number)) # this line imports the lists from csv files - works
data.2 <- lapply(data, data.table) # seems to work
row.remove <- lapply(data.2, function(x) x[!(data.2$A = seq(from=1,to=4,by=2)) # no error message, but deletes all the rows
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would start with renaming your `list` variable

Comment: How come? I don't understand.

Comment: your inner call `!(list$A = seq(from=1, to=4, by=2))` will be always equal to `seq(from=1, to=4, by=2)`

Comment: Just fyi, this doesn't make sense.  What are you doing in `row.remove`?  There is no assigned variable `list`

Comment: I have a lot to learn about how to use functions - thank you for pointing that out, Richard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
for (i in 1:5){
    file.number = i
    data <- setNames(lapply(paste(file.number,".csv"), read.csv, paste(file.number))
    data <- as.data.table(data)
    row.remove <- data[!(data$A = seq(from=1,to=4,by=2) )]
}
```

Instead of analyzing the list simultaneously, this will analyze the lists one by one. It's not a full solution, but more of a work around.